# chown -R root:root .* in /root performs chown on /

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, chown

When running the command in the title from /root it somehow jumps up to / and changes ownership for ALLfiles, i only noticed because error messages for /proc popped up.

Maybe i'm getting old but should . and .. not be ignored by any command ? AFAIK these are there because of the filesystem and serve no other purpose.

running Debian Wheezy with latest updates applied.

Answer (score 4):

> Maybe i'm getting old but should . and .. not be ignored by any command ? AFAIK these are there because of the filesystem and serve no other purpose.

That would make no sense, simply because you specifically fed the names `.` and `..` to chown by your `chown <...> .*`. In such an instance, why should `chown` think that you didn't do what you wanted to do?

The names were fed to chown because the shell expanded them based on the shell glob expansion criteria you gave it, which matched both `.` and `..` along with every other dot-directory in the current directory. Since you told `chown` to work recursively, it descended into those directories and anything below them. This means it "descended into" `..` and then kept working from there.

You can try this out yourself by doing `echo .*` to see the names that were fed into chown's command line. Compare that to the output of `echo *` with `shopt dotglob` on and off respectively (`shopt -s dotglob` to turn on, `shopt -u dotglob` to turn off). Use `ls` rather than `echo` to see the first level of recursion.

**There are perfectly valid reasons** for running even a `chown -R` on either `.` or `..`. The most obvious seems to be to extract an archive that has incorrect ownership information on files and all files within a single directory; in such a case, `chown -R abc:xyz .` from within the uncompressed directory is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, to reset ownership to something reasonable on your system.

If you want your shell to not expand `.*` into `.` and `..` then you need to make sure that it is set up correctly for your particular shell. For example, quoting from the GNU bash 4.2.37(1)-release (current on Debian Wheezy at the time of this writing, Debian `bash` package version `4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7u3` on amd64 architecture) man page:

> **GLOBIGNORE**
>    A colon-separated list of patterns defining the  set  of  file names  to  be  ignored  by  pathname  expansion.  If a filename matched by a pathname expansion pattern also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.

Remember that part of the Unix philosophy is "trust that the user knows what they are doing".

Comment: I was trained in unix in 1993.

Comment: Any manipulation on . or .. is prohibited. Therefor we use ./ or ../ since chown .. may make the chown command behave in undesirable way.

from TLDP bash beginners guide on filename expansion

The GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file names matching a pattern. If GLOBIGNORE is set, each matching file name that also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE is removed from the list of matches. The file names . and .. are always ignored, even when GLOBIGNORE is set.

Comment: @J.Lambrecht "I was trained in unix in 1993." Then you should know that Unix != Linux != GNU. Linux was just starting to gain momentum in 1993, and GNU was still quite primitive compared to today. I added a quote from the bash man page on my system, which happens to be a current Debian Wheezy. It does not indicate at all that `.` and `..` are implicitly the list if $GLOBIGNORE is not set.

Comment: The TLDP [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) was last updated six and a half years ago (20081227). For comparison, at that time for [GNU bash](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/), 3.2 appears to have been current.

Comment: To avoid `..` being included in the expansion list, use `.[^.]*`: this will expand into all files beginning with `.` except `.` and `..`. Check by comparing `echo .*` with `echo .[^.]*`. (For the record, I learned Unix in 1985.)

Comment: @AFH I do that all the time, but it's not what the OP asked about, so I didn't include that in my answer.

Comment: What is this, a breeding ground for autism ?
Thanks AFH, that is the most useful comment thus far.

Comment: @J.Lambrecht The only question I see in your question is "should . and .. not be ignored by any command?". Stack Exchange in general works by providing answers to *the question as asked*; we don't go around and *guess* what you ask (and we even put questions on hold so they cannot be answered if the question is not clear about what is being asked, until the question is fixed, hopefully by the OP). If you wanted to know how to avoid that behavior, you should have asked about that rather than whether `.` and `..` should be ignored by "any command".

Comment: thanks anyway, i was seriously shocked, never ran into unexpected behaviour with filename expansion, until friday

Answer (score 1):

1. Dot (.) can't be ignored because is current directory
2. Double dot (..) (upper directory) will not be ignored because it mach the wildcard

But if you exec it on this way you will have not such effect

```
chown -R root:root *
```

If you want to change only hidden files, directories try this:

```
find . -regex '.*/\..*' -exec chown root:root {} \;
```

Comment: using * is not the same as using .*

Comment: check http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html all the way down on the page under 'filename expansion' it explicitly states it should ignore . and ..

Comment: So you want to do this only for hidden files and directories. See my edited answer

Comment: i cannot believe this, . and .. MUST be ignored unless these are used as ./ and ../ it violates the very use behaviour of chown having to embed it in an extensive command

Comment: @J.Lambrecht `.` and `..` are ignored only when the non-dotted-* fileglob is given. `.*` will match `.` and `..` and `.foo` and `.bar`.  Basically, `*` doesn't include "hidden" files, meaning anything beginning with `.` but `.*` overrides that behavior to include _anything_ starting with a `.`, and yes, that includes the directories. PS. I was trained in '89. :/

Comment: sigh. Never ever had this happen to me before. I even forgot about filename expansion "rules" after all that time. Still, i'm miffed because it changes the line of behaviour when  handling files. The .files should not be a cause for exception. My ego took a hit i guess.